# How To Negate the Formal Definition of an Injective Function

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

in my linear algebra class, the professors gave us a formal definition of an injective function, which is

Given a function f,
if $\forall$ x, x' $\in$ $R$ where x $\ne$  x' $\implies$ f(x) $\ne$ f(x'), then f is injective.

I am trying to negate this statement for a proof, but am unsure if I am thinking of this correctly. From what I am able to deduce, this can be broken down into its logical statements. The definition says that we have a P which implies a Q. In this case, the P is [$\forall$ x, x' $\in$ $R$ where x $\ne$  x' $\implies$ f(x) $\ne$ f(x')], and Q is [f is injective.] And if we look at the statement P, we can think about that in terms of R implies T. This is where I get tripped up. The P is [∀ x, x' ∈ R where x ≠ x'] and the Q is [f(x) ≠ f(x')]. Q is clearly a statement. f(x) either does or does not equal f(x'). But, R, which is [∀  x, x' ∈ R where x ≠ x'] does not have a truth value - or the truth value is dependent on x $\ne$ x', which still does not make sense to me.

I say that it does not make sense because I don't understand how to negate this statement. Negating P $\implies$ Q can be written as P $\wedge$ $\neg$Q. This would be equivalent to

[$\forall$ x, x' $\in$ $R$ where x $\ne$  x' $\implies$ f(x) $\ne$ f(x')] $\wedge$ [f is not injective].

While that is logically true, that does not give us any insight into the type of function that a non-injective function is. Intuitively speaking, a function that is not injective can be written as

if $\exists$ x, x' $\in$ $R$ where x $\ne$  x' $\implies$ f(x) = f(x'), then f is not injective.

I cannot figure out how to use logical equivalencies and negations to arrive at that statement. Any help with understanding how to arrive at this definition from the original definition is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When your professor asked you to "negate the definition of an injective function", I'm certain they wanted you to just simplify $\lnot((\forall x, x' \in \Bbb{R})(x \neq x' \implies f(x) \neq f(x'))$. That is, they wanted you to state what it means for a function to *not* be injective. You don't have to include $Q : f$ is injective as part of the negation. After all $((\forall x, x' \in \Bbb{R})(x \neq x' \implies f(x) \neq f(x')) \implies f$ is injective is a tautology, and its negation is simply $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of your confusion is that the definition you quoted is actually not fully formal, it mixes up English and symbols of formal logic in a bit loosy manner.
 If I was to give a definition of an injective function I would not write
$$ \forall x,\ x' \in R \  where\  x \ne  x' \implies f(x) \ne f(x')$$
but instead I would say that a function $f: R \rightarrow S$ is injective if and only if
$$ \forall x,\ x' \in R: x \neq x' \implies f(x) \ne f(x').$$
And now the negation is easy:
$$ \exists x,\ x' \in R: x \neq x' \land f(x) = f(x').$$

From formal point of view, the literal definition you quoted is incorrect (more strictly speaking it is not even a definition - precisely for the fact that "$x,\ x'\ where\ x \neq x'$" is not a sentence) - so no point in trying to negate it.